# calling registerForRemoteNotifications immediately after registerUserNotificationSettings?

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios9

According to apple's [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2) it suggests to register for notifications this way:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {
   // other setup tasks here....

   // Register the supported interaction types.
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                 UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
                [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

   // Register for remote notifications.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

As shown above, it calls `registerForRemoteNotifications` immediately after `registerUserNotificationSettings` , but when the application is opened for the **first time** it wont succeed to get the access token because the user hasn't granted notification permission yet.

In this way, the application will get the access token just if it was opened for the second time.

**Why does apple suggest that?**

What I suggest is calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` in `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` because it will be called after the user grant notification permission.

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings){


       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    }
```

**Is my suggestion correct ?**

Comment: yes your suggestion is 100% correct.

Comment: @Bhumika Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is correct. You may always want to post an NSNotification is you want to handle the failure in your view controller.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
if (notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    // same as response to didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    NSDictionary* data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"" forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationsRegistered" object:self userInfo:data];
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also check condition for notification error.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print("Got token data! \(deviceToken)")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Couldn't register: \(error)")
}
```

And if you want to check for Notification setting then use this method :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings){

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,but there will no be any error or exception if i call registerForRemoteNotifications() when user didn't grant permission

Answer (score 0):

When we request a permission from user to allow sending notifications from our app, with code like:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]
) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
        getNotificationSettings()
    }
}
```

Use this function **getNotificationSettings()**, to call registerForRemoteNotifications() immediately after user allow to get notifications from our app:

```
func getNotificationSettings() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
    print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
    guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      print("done with registerForRemoteNotifications()")
    }
  } 
}
```

source: https://www.kodeco.com/11395893-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started?page=2 (also check first page)